# Nesting a Case statement inside a sum - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Having trouble with this :

I have the following query which gives me exactly the view I need.

```
SELECT t.Week,
       SUM(t.Hours) AS AH,
       SUM(c.Input) AS input,
       SUM(c.[recruitedPos]) AS recruitedPos,
       (SUM(t.Hours) - SUM(c.Input)) AS Possible
FROM tempPOC AS t
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT Week,
                       SUM(input) AS Input,
                       SUM([Normal Weekly Hours]) AS recruitedPos,
                       Shop
                FROM colData
                GROUP BY week,
                         Shop) AS c ON t.Week = c.Week
                                   AND c.Shop = t.Store
GROUP BY t.Week,
         t.Store
ORDER BY t.Week;
```

What I'm having trouble with is writing a case statement to set any values from possible alias to 0 if they are lower than 0.

I thought this would be as simple as

```
(CASE(SUM(t.Hours - c.Hours)) < 0 then 0 else Possible end as Possible)
```

but this is giving me error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Input :

```
Week, AH, Input, RecruitedPos, Possible
1,    15, 25,    13,            -10
1,    30, 15,    15,            15
```

expected output :

```
Week, AH, Input, RecruitedPos, Possible
1,    15, 25,    13,            0  
1,    30, 15,    15,            15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CASE
    WHEN SUM(t.Hours) - SUM(c.Input) < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE SUM(t.Hours) - SUM(c.Input)
END AS Possible
```

Comment: Perfect, will accept in 8 mins. Thanks buddy. mind explaining for my benefit and others? : )

Comment: First you were missing the `WHEN` keyword. Then you were self referencing your expression name in your expression which would make it recursive and it's not allowed in this context.